# CloudKit custom zone notification seems broken on OSX

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, icloud, cloudkit

I'm fairly new to CloudKit and I'm stuck with custom zone notifications.
In short, I'm not able to receive these notifications on OS X Yosemite.
When I register my app for notifications, application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: is called with a valid token but the notification method (didReceiveRemoteNotification) is never called.
On iOS on the other hand, everything works fine.

Any help is deeply appreciated!
Malte

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Did you manage to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with my app. I am not exactly sure what the issues are but I suspect one of the two reasons.
CouldKit uses push notifications to notify your app from the cloudKit server environment once a change has happened.

- This requires your app (and user to accept) using push notifications. So check that these are enabled for your app on your iOS device and OS X system preferences
- It also seems that push notifications only work in the production environment. But I am not 100% sure on that, just a suspicion.

I ended up polling for changes because on iOS users will see an alert asking on if they want to accept push notifications for your app. Although the notifications will stay invisible to the user, users are afraid of being annoyed by your app and oftentimes opt-out. So you need a fallback anyway.